# ibtool error Couldn't open shared capabilities memory GSCapabilities (No such file or directory)

Tags: iphone, localization, interface-builder

I'm using ibtool to localize nibs. I exported string files, translated them, and now trying to apply translated strings back to the nibs using ibtool once again. It works for the most parts except that for some files (about 25% of all nibs) I get the following error:

Couldn't open shared capabilities memory GSCapabilities (No such file or directory)

What can cause that?

Comment: Was a solution ever found?  I'm having the same problem and have not found any useful information.

Comment: I would love to know what this is about as well.

Comment: Not quite sure what happened, but the problem just disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and figured out that
it was because the version of ibtool was wrong as I had both XCode 4.2 and 3.2 installed

We had two ibtool of two different versions of XCode
/Developer-3.2.6/usr/bin/ibtool
/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool
I was using InterfaceBuilder under XCode 3.2.6 but the ibtool was from XCode 4.2

With the right version of ibtool, it can apply the translation back to the xib

/Developer-3.2.6/usr/bin/ibtool --strings-file zh-Hans.lproj/something.xib --write zh-Hans.lproj/something.xib English.lproj/something.xib

ibtool does not have a version inquiry option; as for "shared capabilities memory GSCapabilities", I had to say that the error messages in XCode tend to be consistently irrelevant as before.

Hope this helps.

Yushen